# Cannot find button to add reference to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Visual Studio. I'm trying to add a reference for `System.Windows.Forms` to my C# project for Unity. I don't have any experience adding references.

However, right-clicking "references" does not give me the option to add one. (I can't find the dependencies node.) Most sources say that is the way to go, such as Microsoft's [How to: Add or remove references by using the Reference Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019).

Here are some screenshots:

[Right-clicking references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gerz.jpg)

[Right-clicking the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKtoW.jpg)

So it would be nice if I could find a button for adding references. Thanks.

EDIT: I found it. It was in the "Project" dropdown menu at the top. Thanks, commenters.

Comment: Unity projects are meant for all gaming platforms. `System.Windows.Forms` is for Windows desktop (WinForms), which should not be used there.

Comment: Have you tried the Project menu? There should be an Add Reference listed.

Comment: If you found an answer, post it as an answer and remove it from the question (it isn't a question, but an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the "Project" dropdown menu at the top of the window had the option to add a reference. I had to have a script under the project open in the editor as well.

I'll try to find another way to implement my thing, because Lex Li is probably right; Unity games are cross-platform and all. But this is useful information for the future.
Thank y'all.